# InetAddress.getLocalHost() always returns 127.0.0.1

Tags: java, centos

Anyone knows why InetAddress.getLocalHost() always returns 127.0.0.1 although I have changed the ip inside /etc/hosts? After the change

```
hostname -i
```

returns the correct ip (192.168.x.x), but InetAddress.getLocalHost() is still the name.

I'm using jdk 1.6.0_31 by the way, on CentOS 6.2. Thanks!

Comment: Did you restart the networking service?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jeshurun. I rebooted the server.

Answer (score 1):

because you have to restart your pc or clear dns cache to "apply" the changes

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have rebooted the server and cleared the cache using this command: service nscd restart. But it's still the same.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a security restriction issue. From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost%28%29):

> If there is a security manager, its checkConnect method is called with
>   the local host name and -1 as its arguments to see if the operation is
>   allowed. If the operation is not allowed, an InetAddress representing
>   the loopback address is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have idea how I'm able to check the security restriction?

Comment: @Jingwei: [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html) link about security manager might help you.

Comment: Thanks @Keppil. I'm running the rmi testcase in the command line to minimize the influence of any containers. According to the link `Typically, a web applet runs with a security manager provided by the browser or Java Web Start plugin. Other kinds of applications normally run without a security manager, unless the application itself defines one.` I shouldn't be using any Security Manager. To double confirm this, I checked the value of `System.getSecurityManager()`, which returns null. Therefore, I don't thin it's because of the SecurityManager.

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but maybe this info will be helpful to someone else - I've struggled to find the information documented anywhere (maybe because it's not a formal part of the language spec), and had to determine via experimentation.

If the problem isn't down to the SecurityManager, then the most likely problem is that your name resolution at the OS level is screwed up somehow.

At least on all Unix platforms that I've tested on (OS X, Solaris, Linux), the process used by Java is:

1. Determine local hostname
2. Resolve that via /etc/hosts to determine IP address

I've seen this broken by badly-configured /etc/hosts, such as:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost myhost
1.2.3.4   myhost
```

to give exactly the symptoms described above.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all **LocalHost will always represents the LoopBack address 127.0.0.1**(which is used to
   debug the TCP/IP stack.) when Security manager founds that the operation is not allowed.
2. For your LAN address use `InetAddress.getByName("PC NAME").getHostAddress()`

   **Please replace PC NAME with your Pc Name.**

**Eg:**

```
public class StrTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


            System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName("Vicky-PC").getHostAddress());

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The prob is it's part of the java's RMI implementation that I can't change.